# MySQL - Faster way than C API (data copying)

Tags: c++, c, mysql-connector, mysql

My C++ software uses the MySQL C API (libmysqlclient).  It uses `mysql_query`, `mysql_use_result`, `mysql_fetch_row`, etc.  Then, it builds a C++ class that represents the database record.

We designed our method over 10 years ago, and not sure if there's now a faster way.

It drives me nuts how much copying is going on behind the scenes, i.e. if my class has a string, first that data is copied into the MYSQL_RES*, then to be parsed and copied into the string.

Is there a more efficient way to be doing this, to directly initialize my C++ class's variables to avoid data copying?

Is there any significant speed benefits to using the C or C++ connector?  (Presumably they reduce the amount of code needed, but that's long been written for us.)

Comment: The choice of the binding language and _data copying_, won't be the real performance bottleneck of your application. So what you're bothering about?

Comment: So, putting aside whether it's a real performance concern, there's no more efficient way than having the database results copied into the mysql structures, then re-copying those into my classes?